# Which text mining/NLP method can I use given my purpose?

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I am doing a piece of research. Respondents take a survey, and are asked to:

1) imagine they are buying a product(say, a cell phone) 
2) rate the importance of marketing information (e.g., advertisements) when they are gathering information prior to making a purchase, on a 0-10 scale
3) they are asked what specific characteristics of the product led them to rate the marketing information the way they did.

A sample response is like this:
1) importance rating: 8

2) "Marketing is important because it highlights the differences in the **many product alternative**s. Cell phones are **complex** products and we can not gather and absorb all the information available about all the alternatives. Also, cell phone **technology** is always **advancing**, which worsens this problem."

Product characteristics that can be manually extracted from this single response: product complexity, multitude of product alternatives, pace of technological advancement of the product

The same survey is done for 13 other products, and also 3 other sources of information besides marketing information (4 in total). 200 respondents.

**Goal**: developing a list of product characteristics that determine the importance of each of the 4 sources information.

**Question**: What quantitative method can I use in R or Python to extract this list out of the qualitative responses I have?

This is significant research for me, and I highly appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Let me rephrase the question that you wanted to ask (hopefully my guess is right) in a broader sense. You have for example online reviews and you want to model different products' aspects. This is an interesting domain researchers are working on and its formal name is aspect-sentiment modeling. Sometimes people name this as hidden topic modeling or opinion mining. I have seen few prior works which proposes hierarchical aspect sentiment model. Please have a look into this [paper](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~mbcusick/papers/kim2013hierarchical.pdf).

You can look into some [unsupervised approach](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1858121) as well. Since you want to learn specific set of characteristics that people are talking about, you can think about them as hidden topics. Explore this [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2883072) to get better understanding. You can model the problem as sentiment analysis as well. There is plenty of prior works and still people are working on it.

Python and R implementation: I am not an expert in R, so i am just talking about python. For topic modeling in python, you can follow [this](https://de.dariah.eu/tatom/topic_model_python.html) write up. For sentiment analysis, best thing in python is NLTK. This [GitHub](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Sentiment-Analysis) repository will take you to a very good set of examples. You will see opinion mining related stuffs as well. Note that this is a very good set of examples and should help you to build a good model that will serve your purpose. Finally let me give links of some GitHub Repositories which might help you to understand this problem domain more rigorously.

Examples: (1) [Yelp Summarization Miner](https://github.com/Fossj117/opinion-mining) (2) [Joint aspect and sentiment modeling](https://github.com/wenzheli/ReviewMining) (3) [Jointly modeling aspects, rating and sentiments](https://github.com/nihalb/JMARS) (4) [Opinion Phrase Extraction](https://github.com/vladsandulescu/phrases)

Answer (score 1):

If the importance rating for each source is already available from the responses, you need to only extract product characteristics. Then you can determine for each product characteristic its association with a rating score.

The size of your data seems too small to be used with methods like topic modelling. So you can train topic models on a large collection of reviews of similar products. There are a few such collections, see, e.g., links on [this page](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html#datasets) (the Amazon corpus in particular contains reviews on various electronic goods). For topic modelling in Python you can use [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) ([tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html)) or 
[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) ([example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-topics-extraction-with-nmf-lda-py)). Hopefully, most topics will correspond to product characteristics. Then you can assign topics in each of your reviews using the topic models trained on the larger collection.

If you do not have a sufficiently large collection of relevant reviews, you can extract key phrases from your reviews, using one of the libraries described [here](http://textminingonline.com/getting-started-with-keyword-extraction). They will not be arranged into "topics", so you would be using actual key phrases in your analysis.

Once you have topics or key phrases, you can find, e.g., the mean importance rating associated with each of them.